# UIViewController abstract class's subview display in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a subview in a UIViewController abstract class and have that subview show up in Interface Builder when I make a subclass of it.  Similarly, when I make a subclass of UITableViewCell, contentView (UIView) is by default in the View hierarchy, in Interface Builder.

Apologies in advance if this question has been asked before.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to a subview that is created programatically in your UIViewController subclass?  If so, then, no, programatic content is not rendered in Interface Builder.  You can use `@IBDesignable` on a UIView subclass to have it rendered in Interface Builder

Comment: The subview (container view) would actually be created in the super class.  The idea is that this container view would show up in Interface Builder if I created a subclass of the super class and I could place other views inside it.  Sounds like the only way would be to create a UIView subclass and make it IBDesignable.  Not really the same but at least the custom view will be reusable.